# Target iframe element in active Bootstrap carousel slide and add a hash to the SRC attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, append

I have iframe elements embedded in a [Bootstrap carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) on my page. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active">
<iframe src="http://iframe.url/index.html" width="160" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="item">
<iframe src="http://another.iframe.url/index.html" width="300" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

I need help writing a script that will target the visible slide and append `#play` to the iframe element SRC attribute. I am thinking I can do this by targeting the Bootstrap `.item .active` classes that are automatically set when a slide is visible in the carousel.

For example, the active slide iframe element should look like this: `<iframe src="http://another.iframe.url/index.html#play" width="300" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

How can I accomplish this with Javascript or jQuery? Thank you for your help.

I started writing an idea for a way to accomplish this here but it doesn't work:

```
// Trigger Active Slide to Play
$('.carousel').carousel().on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
$(this).find('.active.item').('iframe', e.relatedTarget) {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src') + '#play');
});
});
```

*EDIT* I have been trying to come up with a solution. This still does not work but I think it is getting closer to what I am looking for:

```
// Trigger Active Slide to Play
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
var activeItem = $(this).find('.active.item');
if (parent().is(activeItem)) {
    $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', function() {
        return $(this).attr('src') + "#play"
    })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a working code:

```
    $('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
      $(this).find('.active.item').attr('src', function(){
        return $(this).attr('src') + "#play"
      })
     });
```

You had a typo in 'slide.bs.carousel', also trying to use an event wasn't necessary, otherwise the logic is fine.

Make sure you remove #play when it gets inactive.

Comment: This seems to add the logic to the div above the iframe element. This is happening when the script runs: `<div class="item active" src="undefined#play">` The `iframe` element is a child element of this div. How can I change this script to target the child `iframe` element instead of the `.active.item`?

Comment: $('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
      $(this).find('.active.item').children('iframe').attr('src', function(){
        return $(this).attr('src') + "#play"
      })
     });

add children('iframe) to target iframe.